# occupancy reports for hospitals

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm using `sql2008r2` and I need a report for bed occupancy. For this I just created a view and fields like these:

`registrationid,name,admitdate,dischargedate,accomodationdate,branchid`.

I need the result like branchwise occupancy as follow:

`Date,openingbalance,totaladmission,totaldischarge,Closingbalance`.

Here Opening balance means for example if I take the report on todays occupancy then openingbalance is the yesterdays closing.

Also `closing balance means Opening +totaladmission-totaldischarge`.

I got `totaladmission` and `totaldischarge`.

How to get Opening balance in same row?

```
PatientCode PatientName AdmissionDate   DischargeDate   Roomlogdate RoomName    HospitalBranchID    RoomTypeMasterName  IsDischarged    RegistrationID
N294    AAD 06-04-2015  24-04-2015  24-04-2015  Own-11  49  Own 1   157480
N294    AAD 06-04-2015  24-04-2015  23-04-2015  Own-11  49  Own 1   157480
N294    AAD 06-04-2015  24-04-2015  22-04-2015  Own-11  49  Own 1   157480
N294    AAD 06-04-2015  24-04-2015  21-04-2015  Own-11  49  Own 1   157480
N294    AAD 06-04-2015  24-04-2015  20-04-2015  Own-11  49  Own 1   157480
N294    AAD 06-04-2015  24-04-2015  19-04-2015  Own-11  49  Own 1   157480
N294    AAD 06-04-2015  24-04-2015  18-04-2015  Own-11  49  Own 1   157480
N294    AAD 06-04-2015  24-04-2015  17-04-2015  Own-11  49  Own 1   157480
N294    AAD 06-04-2015  24-04-2015  16-04-2015  Own-11  49  Own 1   157480
N294    AAD 06-04-2015  24-04-2015  15-04-2015  Own-11  49  Own 1   157480
N294    AAD 06-04-2015  24-04-2015  14-04-2015  Own-11  49  Own 1   157480
N294    AAD 06-04-2015  24-04-2015  13-04-2015  Own-11  49  Own 1   157480
N294    AAD 06-04-2015  24-04-2015  12-04-2015  Own-11  49  Own 1   157480
N294    AAD 06-04-2015  24-04-2015  11-04-2015  Own-11  49  Own 1   157480
N294    AAD 06-04-2015  24-04-2015  10-04-2015  Own-11  49  Own 1   157480
N294    AAD 06-04-2015  24-04-2015  09-04-2015  Own-11  49  Own 1   157480
N294    AAD 06-04-2015  24-04-2015  08-04-2015  Own-11  49  Own 1   157480
N294    AAD 06-04-2015  24-04-2015  07-04-2015  Own-11  49  Own 1   157480
N294    AAD 06-04-2015  24-04-2015  06-04-2015  Own-11  49  Own 1   157480
N294    AAD 31-03-2014  16-04-2014  16-04-2014  Own-1   49  Own 1   88975
N294    AAD 31-03-2014  16-04-2014  15-04-2014  Own-1   49  Own 1   88975
N294    AAD 31-03-2014  16-04-2014  14-04-2014  Own-1   49  Own 1   88975
N294    AAD 31-03-2014  16-04-2014  13-04-2014  Own-1   49  Own 1   88975
N294    AAD 31-03-2014  16-04-2014  12-04-2014  Own-1   49  Own 1   88975
N294    AAD 31-03-2014  16-04-2014  11-04-2014  Own-1   49  Own 1   88975
N294    AAD 31-03-2014  16-04-2014  10-04-2014  Own-1   49  Own 1   88975
N294    AAD 31-03-2014  16-04-2014  09-04-2014  Own-1   49  Own 1   88975
N294    AAD 31-03-2014  16-04-2014  08-04-2014  Own-1   49  Own 1   88975
N294    AAD 31-03-2014  16-04-2014  07-04-2014  Own-1   49  Own 1   88975
N294    AAD 31-03-2014  16-04-2014  06-04-2014  Own-1   49  Own 1   88975
N294    AAD 31-03-2014  16-04-2014  05-04-2014  Own-1   49  Own 1   88975
N294    AAD 31-03-2014  16-04-2014  04-04-2014  Own-1   49  Own 1   88975
N294    AAD 31-03-2014  16-04-2014  03-04-2014  Own-1   49  Own 1   88975
N294    AAD 31-03-2014  16-04-2014  02-04-2014  Own-1   49  Own 1   88975
N294    AAD 31-03-2014  16-04-2014  01-04-2014  Own-1   49  Own 1   88975
N294    AAD 31-03-2014  16-04-2014  31-03-2014  Own-1   49  Own 1   88975
N294    AAD 25-03-2013  10-04-2013  10-04-2013  Own-4   49  Own 1   37204
N294    AAD 25-03-2013  10-04-2013  09-04-2013  Own-4   49  Own 1   37204
N294    AAD 25-03-2013  10-04-2013  08-04-2013  Own-4   49  Own 1   37204
N294    AAD 25-03-2013  10-04-2013  07-04-2013  Own-4   49  Own 1   37204
N294    AAD 25-03-2013  10-04-2013  06-04-2013  Own-4   49  Own 1   37204
N294    AAD 25-03-2013  10-04-2013  05-04-2013  Own-4   49  Own 1   37204
N294    AAD 25-03-2013  10-04-2013  04-04-2013  Own-4   49  Own 1   37204
N294    AAD 25-03-2013  10-04-2013  03-04-2013  Own-4   49  Own 1   37204
N294    AAD 25-03-2013  10-04-2013  02-04-2013  Own-4   49  Own 1   37204
N294    AAD 25-03-2013  10-04-2013  01-04-2013  Own-4   49  Own 1   37204
N294    AAD 25-03-2013  10-04-2013  31-03-2013  Own-4   49  Own 1   37204
N294    AAD 25-03-2013  10-04-2013  30-03-2013  Own-4   49  Own 1   37204
N294    AAD 25-03-2013  10-04-2013  29-03-2013  Own-4   49  Own 1   37204
N294    AAD 25-03-2013  10-04-2013  28-03-2013  Own-4   49  Own 1   37204
N294    AAD 25-03-2013  10-04-2013  27-03-2013  Own-4   49  Own 1   37204
N294    AAD 25-03-2013  10-04-2013  26-03-2013  Own-4   49  Own 1   37204
N294    AAD 25-03-2013  10-04-2013  25-03-2013  Own-4   49  Own 1   37204
1303-94 bb  14-03-2013  25-03-2013  25-03-2013  306-2   49  Ward    1   36581
1303-94 bb  14-03-2013  25-03-2013  24-03-2013  306-2   49  Ward    1   36581
1303-94 bb  14-03-2013  25-03-2013  23-03-2013  306-2   49  Ward    1   36581
1303-94 bb  14-03-2013  25-03-2013  22-03-2013  306-2   49  Ward    1   36581
1303-94 bb  14-03-2013  25-03-2013  21-03-2013  306-2   49  Ward    1   36581
1303-94 bb  14-03-2013  25-03-2013  20-03-2013  306-2   49  Ward    1   36581
1303-94 bb  14-03-2013  25-03-2013  19-03-2013  306-2   49  Ward    1   36581
1303-94 bb  14-03-2013  25-03-2013  18-03-2013  306-2   49  Ward    1   36581
1303-94 bb  14-03-2013  25-03-2013  17-03-2013  306-2   49  Ward    1   36581
1303-94 bb  14-03-2013  25-03-2013  16-03-2013  306-2   49  Ward    1   36581
1303-94 bb  14-03-2013  25-03-2013  15-03-2013  306-2   49  Ward    1   36581
1303-94 bb  14-03-2013  25-03-2013  14-03-2013  306-2   49  Ward    1   36581
1503-863    ag  31-03-2015  19-04-2015  19-04-2015  PH-1A-3 49  Outside Rooms   1   156582
1503-863    ag  31-03-2015  19-04-2015  18-04-2015  PH-1A-3 49  Outside Rooms   1   156582
1503-863    ag  31-03-2015  19-04-2015  17-04-2015  PH-1A-3 49  Outside Rooms   1   156582
1503-863    ag  31-03-2015  19-04-2015  16-04-2015  PH-1A-3 49  Outside Rooms   1   156582
1503-863    ag  31-03-2015  19-04-2015  15-04-2015  PH-1A-3 49  Outside Rooms   1   156582
1503-863    ag  31-03-2015  19-04-2015  14-04-2015  PH-1A-3 49  Outside Rooms   1   156582
1503-863    ag  31-03-2015  19-04-2015  13-04-2015  PH-1A-3 49  Outside Rooms   1   156582
1503-863    ag  31-03-2015  19-04-2015  12-04-2015  PH-1A-3 49  Outside Rooms   1   156582
1503-863    ag  31-03-2015  19-04-2015  11-04-2015  PH-1A-3 49  Outside Rooms   1   156582
1503-863    ag  31-03-2015  19-04-2015  10-04-2015  PH-1A-3 49  Outside Rooms   1   156582
1503-863    ag  31-03-2015  19-04-2015  09-04-2015  PH-1A-3 49  Outside Rooms   1   156582
1503-863    ag  31-03-2015  19-04-2015  08-04-2015  PH-1A-3 49  Outside Rooms   1   156582
1503-863    ag  31-03-2015  19-04-2015  07-04-2015  PH-1A-3 49  Outside Rooms   1   156582
1503-863    ag  31-03-2015  19-04-2015  06-04-2015  PH-1A-3 49  Outside Rooms   1   156582
1503-863    ag  31-03-2015  19-04-2015  05-04-2015  PH-1A-3 49  Outside Rooms   1   156582
1503-863    ag  31-03-2015  19-04-2015  04-04-2015  PH-1A-3 49  Outside Rooms   1   156582
1503-863    ag  31-03-2015  19-04-2015  03-04-2015  PH-1A-3 49  Outside Rooms   1   156582
1503-863    ag  31-03-2015  19-04-2015  02-04-2015  PH-1A-3 49  Outside Rooms   1   156582
1503-863    ag  31-03-2015  19-04-2015  01-04-2015  PH-1A-3 49  Outside Rooms   1   156582
1503-863    ag  31-03-2015  19-04-2015  31-03-2015  PH-1A-3 49  Outside Rooms   1   156582
1105-637    abd 26-12-2012  09-01-2013  09-01-2013  4257    49  Double Room With TV 1   29661
1105-637    abd 26-12-2012  09-01-2013  08-01-2013  4257    49  Double Room With TV 1   29661
1105-637    abd 26-12-2012  09-01-2013  07-01-2013  4257    49  Double Room With TV 1   29661
1105-637    abd 26-12-2012  09-01-2013  06-01-2013  4257    49  Double Room With TV 1   29661
1105-637    abd 26-12-2012  09-01-2013  05-01-2013  4257    49  Double Room With TV 1   29661
1105-637    abd 26-12-2012  09-01-2013  04-01-2013  4257    49  Double Room With TV 1   29661
1105-637    abd 26-12-2012  09-01-2013  03-01-2013  4257    49  Double Room With TV 1   29661
1105-637    abd 26-12-2012  09-01-2013  02-01-2013  4257    49  Double Room With TV 1   29661
1105-637    abd 26-12-2012  09-01-2013  01-01-2013  4257    49  Double Room With TV 1   29661
1105-637    abd 26-12-2012  09-01-2013  31-12-2012  4257    49  Double Room With TV 1   29661
1105-637    abd 26-12-2012  09-01-2013  30-12-2012  4257    49  Double Room With TV 1   29661
1105-637    abd 26-12-2012  09-01-2013  29-12-2012  4257    49  Double Room With TV 1   29661
1105-637    abd 26-12-2012  09-01-2013  28-12-2012  4257    49  Double Room With TV 1   29661
1105-637    abd 26-12-2012  09-01-2013  27-12-2012  4257    49  Double Room With TV 1   29661
1105-637    abd 26-12-2012  09-01-2013  26-12-2012  4257    49  Double Room With TV 1   29661
1308-80 arp 09-07-2015  23-07-2015  23-07-2015  5019-1  49  V   1   177337
1308-80 arp 09-07-2015  23-07-2015  22-07-2015  5019-1  49  V   1   177337
1308-80 arp 09-07-2015  23-07-2015  21-07-2015  5019-1  49  V   1   177337
1308-80 arp 09-07-2015  23-07-2015  20-07-2015  5019-1  49  V   1   177337
1308-80 arp 09-07-2015  23-07-2015  19-07-2015  5019-1  49  V   1   177337
1308-80 arp 09-07-2015  23-07-2015  18-07-2015  5019-1  49  V   1   177337
1308-80 arp 09-07-2015  23-07-2015  17-07-2015  5019-1  49  V   1   177337
1308-80 arp 09-07-2015  23-07-2015  16-07-2015  5019-1  49  V   1   177337
1308-80 arp 09-07-2015  23-07-2015  15-07-2015  5019-1  49  V   1   177337
1308-80 arp 09-07-2015  23-07-2015  14-07-2015  5019-1  49  V   1   177337
1308-80 arp 09-07-2015  23-07-2015  13-07-2015  5019-1  49  V   1   177337
1308-80 arp 09-07-2015  23-07-2015  12-07-2015  5019-1  49  V   1   177337
1308-80 arp 09-07-2015  23-07-2015  11-07-2015  5019-1  49  V   1   177337
1308-80 arp 09-07-2015  23-07-2015  10-07-2015  5019-1  49  V   1   177337
1308-80 arp 09-07-2015  23-07-2015  09-07-2015  5019-1  49  V   1   177337
1308-80 arp 04-08-2014  19-08-2014  19-08-2014  G-1-2B  49  Outside Rooms   1   111798
1308-80 arp 04-08-2014  19-08-2014  18-08-2014  G-1-2B  49  Outside Rooms   1   111798
1308-80 arp 04-08-2014  19-08-2014  17-08-2014  G-1-2B  49  Outside Rooms   1   111798
1308-80 arp 04-08-2014  19-08-2014  16-08-2014  G-1-2B  49  Outside Rooms   1   111798
1308-80 arp 04-08-2014  19-08-2014  15-08-2014  G-1-2B  49  Outside Rooms   1   111798
1308-80 arp 04-08-2014  19-08-2014  14-08-2014  G-1-2B  49  Outside Rooms   1   111798
1308-80 arp 04-08-2014  19-08-2014  13-08-2014  G-1-2B  49  Outside Rooms   1   111798
1308-80 arp 04-08-2014  19-08-2014  12-08-2014  G-1-2B  49  Outside Rooms   1   111798
1308-80 arp 04-08-2014  19-08-2014  11-08-2014  G-1-2B  49  Outside Rooms   1   111798
1308-80 arp 04-08-2014  19-08-2014  10-08-2014  G-1-2B  49  Outside Rooms   1   111798
1308-80 arp 04-08-2014  19-08-2014  09-08-2014  G-1-2B  49  Outside Rooms   1   111798
1308-80 arp 04-08-2014  19-08-2014  08-08-2014  G-1-2B  49  Outside Rooms   1   111798
1308-80 arp 04-08-2014  19-08-2014  07-08-2014  G-1-2B  49  Outside Rooms   1   111798
1308-80 arp 04-08-2014  19-08-2014  06-08-2014  G-1-2B  49  Outside Rooms   1   111798
1308-80 arp 04-08-2014  19-08-2014  05-08-2014  G-1-2B  49  Outside Rooms   1   111798
1308-80 arp 04-08-2014  19-08-2014  04-08-2014  G-1-2B  49  Outside Rooms   1   111798
1308-80 arp 08-08-2013  20-08-2013  20-08-2013  GH1-2A  49  Guest House-Floor1  1   51580
1308-80 arp 08-08-2013  20-08-2013  19-08-2013  GH1-2A  49  Guest House-Floor1  1   51580
1308-80 arp 08-08-2013  20-08-2013  18-08-2013  GH1-2A  49  Guest House-Floor1  1   51580
1308-80 arp 08-08-2013  20-08-2013  17-08-2013  GH1-2A  49  Guest House-Floor1  1   51580
1308-80 arp 08-08-2013  20-08-2013  16-08-2013  GH1-2A  49  Guest House-Floor1  1   51580
1308-80 arp 08-08-2013  20-08-2013  15-08-2013  GH1-2A  49  Guest House-Floor1  1   51580
1308-80 arp 08-08-2013  20-08-2013  14-08-2013  GH1-2A  49  Guest House-Floor1  1   51580
1308-80 arp 08-08-2013  20-08-2013  13-08-2013  GH1-2A  49  Guest House-Floor1  1   51580
1308-80 arp 08-08-2013  20-08-2013  12-08-2013  GH1-2A  49  Guest House-Floor1  1   51580
1308-80 arp 08-08-2013  20-08-2013  11-08-2013  GH1-2A  49  Guest House-Floor1  1   51580
1308-80 arp 08-08-2013  20-08-2013  10-08-2013  GH1-2A  49  Guest House-Floor1  1   51580
1308-80 arp 08-08-2013  20-08-2013  09-08-2013  GH1-2A  49  Guest House-Floor1  1   51580
1308-80 arp 08-08-2013  20-08-2013  08-08-2013  GH1-2A  49  Guest House-Floor1  1   51580
1505-1041   aan 26-05-2015  10-06-2015  10-06-2015  359 49  Double Room 1   168564
1505-1041   aan 26-05-2015  10-06-2015  09-06-2015  359 49  Double Room 1   168564
1505-1041   aan 26-05-2015  10-06-2015  08-06-2015  359 49  Double Room 1   168564
1505-1041   aan 26-05-2015  10-06-2015  07-06-2015  359 49  Double Room 1   168564
1505-1041   aan 26-05-2015  10-06-2015  06-06-2015  359 49  Double Room 1   168564
1505-1041   aan 26-05-2015  10-06-2015  05-06-2015  359 49  Double Room 1   168564
1505-1041   aan 26-05-2015  10-06-2015  04-06-2015  359 49  Double Room 1   168564
1505-1041   aan 26-05-2015  10-06-2015  03-06-2015  359 49  Double Room 1   168564
1505-1041   aan 26-05-2015  10-06-2015  02-06-2015  359 49  Double Room 1   168564
1505-1041   aan 26-05-2015  10-06-2015  01-06-2015  359 49  Double Room 1   168564
1505-1041   aan 26-05-2015  10-06-2015  31-05-2015  359 49  Double Room 1   168564
1505-1041   aan 26-05-2015  10-06-2015  30-05-2015  359 49  Double Room 1   168564
1505-1041   aan 26-05-2015  10-06-2015  29-05-2015  359 49  Double Room 1   168564
1505-1041   aan 26-05-2015  10-06-2015  28-05-2015  359 49  Double Room 1   168564
1505-1041   aan 26-05-2015  10-06-2015  27-05-2015  359 49  Double Room 1   168564
1505-1041   aan 26-05-2015  10-06-2015  26-05-2015  359 49  Double Room 1   168564
1308-183    aavas   30-06-2014  17-07-2014  17-07-2014  4365    49  Double Room 1   105825
1308-183    aavas   30-06-2014  17-07-2014  16-07-2014  4365    49  Double Room 1   105825
1308-183    aavas   30-06-2014  17-07-2014  15-07-2014  4365    49  Double Room 1   105825
1308-183    aavas   30-06-2014  17-07-2014  14-07-2014  4365    49  Double Room 1   105825
1308-183    aavas   30-06-2014  17-07-2014  13-07-2014  4365    49  Double Room 1   105825
1308-183    aavas   30-06-2014  17-07-2014  12-07-2014  4365    49  Double Room 1   105825
1308-183    aavas   30-06-2014  17-07-2014  11-07-2014  4365    49  Double Room 1   105825
1308-183    aavas   30-06-2014  17-07-2014  10-07-2014  4365    49  Double Room 1   105825
1308-183    aavas   30-06-2014  17-07-2014  09-07-2014  4365    49  Double Room 1   105825
1308-183    aavas   30-06-2014  17-07-2014  08-07-2014  4365    49  Double Room 1   105825
1308-183    aavas   30-06-2014  17-07-2014  07-07-2014  4365    49  Double Room 1   105825
1308-183    aavas   30-06-2014  17-07-2014  06-07-2014  4365    49  Double Room 1   105825
1308-183    aavas   30-06-2014  17-07-2014  05-07-2014  4365    49  Double Room 1   105825
1308-183    aavas   30-06-2014  17-07-2014  04-07-2014  4365    49  Double Room 1   105825
1308-183    aavas   30-06-2014  17-07-2014  03-07-2014  4365    49  Double Room 1   105825
1308-183    aavas   30-06-2014  17-07-2014  02-07-2014  4365    49  Double Room 1   105825
1308-183    aavas   30-06-2014  17-07-2014  01-07-2014  4365    49  Double Room 1   105825
1308-183    aavas   30-06-2014  17-07-2014  30-06-2014  4365    49  Double Room 1   105825
```

Comment: Provide some Sample data and expected output. BTW what is that -3 downvote favorite 1?

Comment: Please try to reformulate your question without domain specific things. Make a small example of what you actually want to achieve. Maybe while bringing the problem to its basics, you will answer your own question! Include the query what you tried. Format your code. (four spaces are your friend). And... Did you just violate HIPAA?

Answer (score 0):

If you create a new table of dates then you can get the opening balance for each day like this:

```
SELECT
    Date
    ,count(registrationid)
FROM
    (
    select
    *
    FROM
    Dates as d left outer join 
    Table as t
        on t.admitdate < d.Date
        and t.DischargeDate >= d.Date
    ) as a
GROUP BY
    Date
```

Date Table:

```
Date
------------
01/01/2014  -- start of analysis period
02/01/2014
..
..
31/12/2015 -- end of analysis period
```

the inner query has one row per day per patient / user that was admitted before that date and discharged that day or after.

the outer query with the group by just aggregates the data by day.

To get closing balances you would just slightly tweak it so that the or equal to wan on the other join clause:

```
SELECT
    Date
    ,count(registrationid)
FROM
    (
    select
    *
    FROM
    Dates as d left outer join 
    Table as t
        on t.admitdate <= d.Date
        and t.DischargeDate > d.Date
    ) as a
GROUP BY
    Date
```

To get all the data in one table you could join together a number of sub queries including this one:

```
SELECT
    D.Date
    ,OpeningBalance
    ,Admissions
    ,Discharges
FROM
    Dates as D
    INNER JOIN 
            (
            SELECT
                Date
                ,count(registrationid) as OpeningBalance
            FROM
                (
                select
                *
                FROM
                Dates as d left outer join 
                Table as t
                    on t.admitdate < d.Date
                    and t.DischargeDate >= d.Date
                ) as a
            GROUP BY
                Date
            ) as OB
        on D.Date = OB.Date
    INNER JOIN 
            (
                SELECT
                Date
                ,count(registrationid) as Admissions
            FROM
                (
                select
                *
                FROM
                Dates as d left outer join 
                Table as t
                    on t.admitdate = d.Date
                ) as a
            GROUP BY
                Date
            ) AS A
        on D.Date = A.Date
    INNER JOIN 
            (
                SELECT
                Date
                ,count(registrationid) as Discharges
            FROM
                (
                select
                *
                FROM
                Dates as d left outer join 
                Table as t
                    on t.DischargeDate = d.Date
                ) as a
            GROUP BY
                Date
            ) AS DC
        on D.Date = DC.Date
```

I am sure there are other ways of doing this but i like the reliability of having a date table.